# Help regarding implicit differentiation.

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I am given the equation:
$x^{a}y^{b} = 6$

Using implicit differentiation I find that the derivative of the equation with respect to y gives:
$\frac{d}{dx}(y) = -\frac{ay}{bx}$.
However when I attempt to differentiate the "regular" way I don`t seem to reach the same answer. I would greatly appreciate someone walking me through the problem.

Comment: is here assumed to be $$y=y(x)?$$

Comment: $x^ay^b$ is an expression not an equation

Comment: You are right, I edited it now.
Yes, y =y(x)

Comment: now it is an equation

Answer (score 0):

then we get
$$ax^{a-1}y^b+x^aby^{b-1}y'=0$$
you must use the product and chain rule:
$$(uv)'=u'v+uv'$$ and since $$y=y(x)$$ the first derivative is given by $$y'(x)$$
$$(x^a)'=ax^{a-1}(x)$$
and $$(y(x)^b)'=by(x)^{b-1}\cdot y'(x)$$

Comment: Could you differentiate it regularly for me? Preferably step-by-step.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: it is nice that i could help you! all the best for you!